# How can I put email messages in a queue when SMTP server is down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have a big problem with my SMTP server for sending emails. It's down often.

At this point I am using this code:

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("fromMail@example.com");
mailMsg.To.Add("toMail@example.com");
mailMsg.Subject = "...";
mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mailMsg.Body = "Mail";
mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("account@gmail.com", "password");
client.Port = 456;         
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mailMsg);
```

But, when my SMTP server is down I want to put all the emails in a queue and when it recovers I want to send them one a time. Is there any way how to do this programatically in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail's SMTP server is down often ? That is strange.

If emailing is vital, I suggest you to use a local queuing service or build your own based on Microsoft Queuing system.

But if it's so vital, I would try to solve my SMTP problem instead.

Comment: Gmail SMTP was just an example. I am using that code with Gmail SMTP because it works and it's never down. The problem is with local SMTP, that's why I need a C# way to put messages in a queue when server is down...

Comment: @jeff If you use IIS as a the SMPTP take a look at MSMQ, send your messages to the MSMQueue instead of directly to SMTP-server. It is already in the system (or needs to be installed), only needs a small adjustment in the code ;)

Comment: Caspar is right, writing in the queue instead of connecting to the service can help. Just store the full email with headers and so on in the spool directory.

Comment: And assuming that I use Gmail SMTP Server, how can I store the emails in queue first and then send them?

Comment: By maintaining your own queuing system. I suggest you the free queuing system available in this project: http://mailsystem.codeplex.com